# Merge sort recursion call explanation in Java

Tags: java, mergesort

I understand the point of recursion and how it works in very simple cases, E.G

```
// Make a func that that will add factorials

public long fact(long n){
  if(n <= 1)
    return 1;
  else
    return n * func(n-1)
}
```

I can see that `n`  decreases with every call and in case if `n = 5` the output will be 120. In this case, I understand how recursion works.

However, when it gets to a little more complex calls, I can't really see what's happening behind the scenes. I can usually understand the code, but would not be able to explain someone why or how is it happening. E.G

```
public void mergeSort(int[] list, int lowIndex, int highIndex){
        if(lowIndex == highIndex)
            return;
        else{
            int midIndex = (lowIndex + highIndex) / 2;
            mergeSort(list, lowIndex, midIndex);
            mergeSort(list, midIndex+1, highIndex);
            merge(list, lowIndex, midIndex, highIndex);
        }
    }
```

I can not figure out how this recursive `mergeSort` calls return what they return.

If we assume that `lowIndex = 0 & midIndex = 5`, what does this method do ?

If someone has some other examples that give good hints in this learning process, that would work nicely as well : )

Comment: what is the `merge()` method in the last statement ?

Comment: It's the method that does the merge logic. I thought it's irrelevant for explaining recursion part.

Comment: Google something like *"mergesort recursive"* and hit **Google Images**. It yields helpful illustrations like this: [Illustration](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/22mergesort/images/mergesortTD.png)

Comment: If you're trying to understand what is returned, then try to understand ***when*** and ***why*** `lowIndex == highIndex` becomes `true`. That's what's responsible for the return of the result of the recursion. --- When you get to understand the *when* and the *why* of that (which is going to involve backtracing what happens through a couple of recursions prior to that evaluation being `true`), then congratulations, you've understood the whole recursion! 

Comment: @Zabuza Why try to understand with still images, when you can see the whole thing happen in a video? https://youtu.be/es2T6KY45cA

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know how the merge logic works.
When you hit the first call of mergeSort(lowIndex,midIndex), it recalls itself  many many times until it will work with a subarray of lenght 2, easy to order ( they need only a comparison).
At this point mergesort(0,1) has been completed and it's time to execute mergesort(2,3) that will return another ordered subarray of length 2; then now in the merge function these subarrays are compared and merged.
So the method ends returning to from where it was called ( in this case from mergesort(0,3) ) and so the next statement to execute is mergesort(4,7). 
Considering N the lenght of the unordered array,the process is repeated until you go back to the top call where the two subarrays of lenght N/2 (or N/2 and N/2 -1 if N is odd) are merged.

Answer (score 0):

This method doesn't return anything. Rather, it manages the divide-and-conquer part of the logic and calls `merge()`, which does an in-place sort of the (sub)array, *mutating* it.

Answer (score 0):

Merge Sort is a divide and conquer algorithm which divided the entire array into two halves and then keeps dividing unless there is a subarray which contains only two elements.The algorithm then goes ahead and merges the sub-array that contains one element after sorting them.
The recursion call stack of the merge sort however is a little hard to grasp at the first go.

Lets say, we have an array 4,0,6,1,5,2,3

Now as per your code above,

Midindex = 3

The first merge sort recursion calls

(list, 0, 3)
When this goes back, since it is recursion and satisfies the base case, 0<3,

we have ,
midindex = 1
so next call is 
(list,0,1)

Again, when this is called, recursively, since 0<1,
we have midindex = 0

so next call is (list,0,0)
this call fails the base case,

So we go to the next line in the code which is
(list, mid+1, high)
this call interprets as (list,1,1) [ Since, as per the above flow, mid was 0]
again list,1,1 fails the base case,
so we move down the code below which is 
merge(list, low,mid,high) 
In this case, this is
(list,0,0,1)

### If you further see  the code for merging, you will see that it sorts the subarray and then merges it. In this case, since it is 4,0

So the subarray after merging would be 0,4.

### This is the completion of the first recursion stack which is nothing but the left side of merge(0,3)

After this the control goes back to completing the right side merge of 0,3
Midindex = 1
So merge sort(list,mid+1,high) [since merge sort(list, low,mid) is already complete above).
This further goes down to, mergesort(list,2,3)
again calling the recursion base case, since 2<3
mid = 2
so, merge sort(list,2,2) and similarly, mergesort(list,3,3). Both these calls will fail the base case and merge function will be called.
This way the recursion stack gets repeated, the final result is a beautiful sorted array.
I hope I am clear.
[image]